# Запятая на стыке двух союзов

Tags: пунктуация

В предложениях типа ///Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю///, пишет Розенталь в пункте 3. параграфа о запятой на стыке двух союзов, запятая после союза "и" не ставится - союз "и" присоединяет целое сложноподчиненное предложение.

Дальше в пункте 4. пишет, что запятая ставится перед союзом "и" и после него, если союз соединяет два простых предложения. Приводится в числе примеров такое предложение: //Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и, когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера.//

Не пойму разницы в этих двух случаях. Вроде оба сложносочиненные предложения, первая часть каждого - простое предложение, а вторая - сложноподчиненное. И запятая после союза "и" должна вроде стоять и в первом примере.

Comment: Примечание 2. Не ставится запятая между главным и следующим за ним придаточным предложением:
б) если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит сочинительный союз (обычно повторяющийся) и, или, либо и т. п., например: Учтите и что он сказал, и как он это сказал; Студент не мог вспомнить ни как называется произведение, ни кто его автор; ср. также при одиночном союзе: Не представлял себе и как он выберется из создавшегося положения;

Comment: тогда, может, Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю - это бессоюзное: вторая часть: и где он теперь, я не знаю. Если переставить в нем главную и придаточную, то получится: я не знаю и где он теперь. И теперь перед и не ставится запятая согласно примечанию 2..

Answer (score 2):

В первом предложении **"Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю**" стык не двух союзов, а  союза и союзного слова ГДЕ. Во втором примере **//Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и, когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера.//**- стык союзов И, КОГДА. Обратите внимание, что между сочинительным союзом и союзным словом запятая  не ставится, а между сочинительным союзом и подчинительным союзом ставится (при отсутствии второй части союза, разумеется).

Comment: Почему Розенталь этого не пояснил?

Comment: Розенталь пишет в этом правиле о стыке двух союзов или союза и союзного слова (относительного слова)

Comment: И ни одного примера с запятой между соч.союзом и союзным словом! Ни у Д.Э. Розенталя, ни у Лопатина. Только между соч. и подч. союзами. Впрочем, один пример (но без запятой!) есть: "В предложениях типа 
//Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю// запятая после союза "и" не ставится" (http://www.classes.ru/grammar/127.Rosental-pravopisanie/49.htm#з_01) А почему не ставится, не объясняет. Потому и не ставится, что тут стык союза и НЕ союза.

Answer (score 1):

В справочнике, по которому я некогда учил русский язык, было написано, что в случае стыка союзов надо смотреть на то, что следует за придаточной. Если там есть "то", "но", "так" и д.р., то не ставим запятую, если же их нет, то ставим.   
Со вторым примером из пункта 4 всё понятно. С первым же не всё так просто. Тут больше смысловой оттенок предложения надо смотреть.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, в предложении "Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю" слово "и" является не сочинительным союзом, а частицей (усилительной). Подобные фразы , на мой взгляд: "И что ты теперь будешь делать?", "И куда ты теперь пойдешь?". По этой причине между частицей "и" и союзным словом "где" запятая не нужна

Comment: Розенталь пишет, что в предложении //Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю/// "и" - союз, присоединяет целое сложноподчиненное предложение. Значит, это не частица. Тем более этот пример приводится на правило - запятая на стыке двух союзов.

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение. Я цитирую Розенталя на память, и, кажется, у него есть и такое замечание о правиле на стыке двух союзов: если убрать придаточное предложение, начавшееся вторым союзом, а структура и смысл предложения не изменится, то запятая на стыке нужна, в противном случае - нет. Уберем "и где он теперь". Получается бессмыслица: "Он давно уже уехал, и... я не знаю". Думаю, так можно объяснить отстутствие запятой после "и", хотя мне и вариант с частицей кажется убедительным. Конечно, Розенталь - это Колосс, но ведь не Христос же.

Comment: Довольно интересно.

Comment: Возможна перестановка придаточного и главного во второй части предложения:Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю.Он давно уже уехал, и я не знаю, где он теперь.
То же самое со вторым примером: 
Крепкий был человек Гуляев, и за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера, когда он вернулся на Урал.

Comment: Но это уже другие предложения, с другой структурой

Answer (score 1):

> > Вроде оба сложносочиненные предложения, первая часть каждого - простое предложение, а вторая - сложноподчиненное

Это так, но вы не учли самое главное. Оговорку о присоединении. 
В первом случае союз И присоединяет всю конструкцию (где он теперь, я не знаю). 
Во втором же примере союз присоединяет только вторую часть всей конструкции (за ним тянулась слава миллионера), а первая (когда он вернулся) подчиняется ей.   
Может быть, на такой схеме будет понятнее:    
***Он давно уже уехал, и {[где он теперь], я не знаю}***  
***Крепкий был человек Гуляев, {и, [когда он вернулся на Урал], за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера}.***
Во втором случае изятие текста в [] не нарушает смысла. В первом такое возможно только в отношении текста в {}.

А можно ссылочку на это место у Розенталя? Если там есть другие примеры, возможно, мне придется ещё подумать. Хотя, вроде, тут все чисто...

//====

Нет, не чисто. В двух интернет-версиях Мамина-Сибиряка запятой этой нет. Что наводит на мысли...

//====

Нашел я источники, извините. Короче, если не брать во внимание отсутствие запятой в электронных версиях М-С, то все складывается. Стуктура присоединения в рассматриваемых случаях разная, ключевым признаком может случить возможность изъятия (в других случаях - перестановки) придаточного во второй части.

ЗЫ Но вообще-то вопрос действительно не из "школьных".

Comment: А что за конструкция "где он теперь, я не знаю"?

Comment: Сложноподчинённое предложение. Я на основы не покунаюсь. Вопрос только в функциях присоединительного союза, т.е. цепляет ли он все целиком или только первй "вагон".

Comment: Почему это сложноподчиненное предложение стало одной конструкцией, а не двумя? Не потому ли, часом, что без придаточной главная несёт уже совсем не тот смысл?

Comment: Ну я вроде об этом и писал... Моежт не в такой формулировке, что несет другой смысл, но "изъятие её невозможожно".  
Повторяю, это мое мнение, но мне кактегорически не нравятся попытки найти объяснение в разграничении созаов и союзых слов. Грамматическая функция у них одна, следовательно и объяненим такое разграничение быть не может.