# Нужно ли второе тире в данном примере?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, приложение

В переводе одна известная фраза звучит так:

> Саурон, враг свободных людей Средиземья, был повержен!

Если мы захотим оформить ее с помощью тире, то нужно ли будет второе:

> Саурон – враг свободных людей Средиземья (–) был повержен.

Насколько я знаю, если приложение выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение, то второе тире опускается.

---

Будет ли действовать данное правило в приведенном примере?

Comment: Если нет тире, то нет и паузы (не подходит).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это правило не будет действовать в данном случае, потому что определяемое слово не имеет общего или образного значения, как в примерах из справочников:
"награда", "страны", "ласточки" далее конкретизируются с помощью приложений.
А *Саурон* – имя (более чем конкретно). Ставим два тире:

*Саурон – враг свободных людей Средиземья – был повержен.*

Пример из [справочника Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#) (пункт 10, 3): *Память об Авиценне — **выдающемся учёном-энциклопедисте, борце за разум и прогресс** — дорога для всего человечества.*

Из [ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120): *Рязанцев и Зоя — **его жена** — были из одного класса; И теперь двое дядей по отцу и Иван Маркович — **дядя матери** — решают задачу.*

Comment: Можно разъяснить, что значит "общее"/"образное" значение?

Comment: @Ajgy  Дерево – общее,  береза – конкретное. Так же и в примерах: наград бывает много, медаль –  более конкретная награда; страны – (какие именно?) участницы чего-то там. А спортсмены названы ласточками – применён образ.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: @Ajgy  Спасибо за вопрос и оценку!

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере приложение относится к имени собственному и обособляется именно на этом основании.
Ср.примеры.

Чемодан внесли кучер Селифан, **низенький человек в тулупчике**, и лакей Петрушка, **малый лет тридцати в подержанном сюртуке** (Г.);

Сергей Никанорыч, **буфетчик**,налил пять стаканов чаю (Ч.);

Безродный человек Маркуша, **дворник,** сидя на полу, строгал палочки и планки для птичьих клеток (М. Г.).

2. На совещании министров иностранных дел стран — **членов Организации американских государств** выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.);

Прилетели сюда первые ласточки — **наши спортсмены** для участия в парусных гонках;

Высшая награда Французского института океанографии за выдающиеся океанографические работы — **медаль в память Альберта I принца Монакского** присуждена видному учёному Л. А. Зенькевичу (Газ.).

Источник силы от матери — **родной земли** представляется для всех источником важным и целебным (второе тире опущено).

В примерах под номером два приложение выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение.

В этих примерах вместо тире возможно и выделение запятыми.

[Розенталь Д.Э. Справочник по русскому языку: Орфография и пунктуация,см.прим.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)

[Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина § 65.п.4,5](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)

Comment: Серж, во всех приведенных примерах (кроме "дворника") выделение жирным не соответствует тому, что должно быть выделено. Надо бы поправить. //  Вы пишете: "Во примерах под номером два...", но этого номера нет в ответе. Также **пп. 4, 5** - это есть в правилах, но не в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо, все исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Этот пункт – один из многочисленных примеров ужасающего непрофессионализма Розенталя при составлении этого справочника. Вот эти строки про ‟определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение” – это буквально бред, который не имеет никакого смысла.
**Тире в первом предложении** – ‟На совещании министров иностранных дел стран — членов Организации американских государств выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.)” – объясняется тем, что здесь определение и приложение равноправны, то есть как в сочетаниях город-герой, гвардейцы-миномётчики, девочки-подростки, зима-волшебница, инженер-конструктор, только здесь приложение распространённое, поэтому ставится тире.
**Тире в третьем предложении** – ‟Высшая награда Французского института океанографии за выдающиеся океанографические работы — медаль в память Альберта I принца Монакского присуждена видному учёному Л. А. Зенькевичу (Газ.)” – объясняется тем, что здесь поясняющее приложение находится перед определяемым сочетанием.
**В третьем предложении** – ‟Прилетели сюда первые ласточки — наши спортсмены для участия в парусных гонках” – просто отсутствует одно тире по причине ошибки (не указано то, откуда это предложение).

В вашем предложении конечно же ставится либо два тире, либо две запятых, так как это приложение и пояснение.

И ещё немного критики Розенталя. Эта тема входит в топ 5 наиболее безумно организованных тем в справочнике. По-моему, даже полный идиот подумал бы о том, как бы разбить эту тему на подтемы, вроде определяемое и приложение, состоящие из одного слова, и определяемое и приложение, где один из членов пары состоит из двух и более слов; даже полный идиот подумал бы о том, как бы обобщить все эти заметки. Но Розенталь просто набрасывает 100500 заметок с лопаты. Маме должно быть стыдно показывать такое.

Comment: В оригинальном справочнике этого пункта нет, не факт, что это вообще Розенталь написал. Его справочники часто дополняют, переделывают чёрт-те как. Берите в библиотеках оригинальные справочники Розенталя, раз критикуете, там всё по-другому.

Comment: А что значит оригинальный справочник Розенталя?

Comment: Ещё ни один лингвист не оспорил это правило. А вы почему-то считаете себя превыше Розенталя, называя его непрофессионалом.

Comment: @Серж Лучше всего "Трудные случаи пунктуации" 1961 года (только в библиотеках). Следующий сомнительный (в плане авторства) и похож на переделанный, он заметно хуже, в том числе и по организации.

Comment: Там, по-моему,в соавторстве с Былинским? У меня должен быть этот справочник в PDf.   Постараюсь посмотреть завтра, если не поленюсь.

Comment: @Серж Былинский — его основной партнёр. Они с ним создали стилистику. У вас не может быть именно второй редакции, её никогда не было в интернете (нет смысла искать), только в библиотеках.

Comment: @oleed, у меня есть справочник: Трудные случаи пунктуации. Сегодня обязательно посмотрю, вечером напишу.

Comment: @Серж У вас первое издание (1959), а не второе. Второе круче всего, нужно оно.

Comment: https://rusneb.ru/catalog/010003_000061_e48fbc84f5b1b76bbed30e2339020821/

Comment: Мне кажется, что этот электронный справочник — это версия В.Ф. Ивановой. Она переделала, сократила и немного бреда добавила, например: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/12468

Comment: @oleedd, да, у меня именно то издание, на которое вы дали первую ссылку.